# React composite components

Tags: reactjs

In my parent component I want to do this

```
import List from '../List'

export default class Example extends Component {
....
  <List>
    <List.Item>
      Author
    </List.Item>
  </List>
}
```

So List.Item is not explicitly imported...

I get this warning due to this:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

So how is it done to dynamically allow child components within a defined component like List.

In List I am using

```
const listItems = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
  if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
    console.log(child)
    return React.cloneElement(
      <ListItem />, child, child.props.children
    )
  }
  // return <ListItem {...child.props} />
})
```

to render the actual ListItems component

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the format `<List><ListItem author={author}/></List>`?

Comment: We need to see the full code for your `List.js` file. We need to see what you are exporting. Or not exporting.

Comment: how do you export your `List` component? Or try `import { List } from './List'`

Answer (score 0):

In List component I can achieve the proxy I want with

```
 List.Item = ''
```

export default List

Then I can import List and use

```
<List>
  <List.Item>...
```